# Open Hyperlink from Excel in frontmost Finder window on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, finder

This is a question on how to get Excel to interact with the Mac Finder. I have a table with hyperlinks that open a particular folder in the Finder:
=HYPERLINK("/path/to/file/", "open")

The folder is opened in a new window in the background. 
Is there a way to make it open the folder in the (already open) frontmost Finder window on Mac?   (and not in a new tab, BTW) 
I assume I would need to write a VBA script for this, but is this possible at all?

The solution provided in the answer below still opens a new Finder window, although the window is placed at exactly the same location on the screen like the frontmost window.  I'm looking for a way to just activate the frontmost Finder window and navigate to the respective folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a mac so i can't veryify but perhaps this solves your question:

```
'should work with formula =hyperlink("/path/to/file/")
'
Sub FollowHyperlink1()
    If LCase(ActiveCell.Formula) Like "*hyperlink*" Then
        'Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=ActiveCell.Value, NewWindow:=True 'Open Folder
    End If
End Sub


'test with a string directly in the cell or in the vba script
'
Sub FollowHyperlink2()
    If LCase(ActiveCell.Formula) Like "*hyperlink*" Then
        'Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=""/path/to/file/", NewWindow:=True 'Open Folder
    End If
End Sub
```

As an alternative Automator or AppleScript might offer a solution?

Comment: That gives me a runtime error `File name or class name not found during Automation operation`  (Debug highlights your `ActiveWorkbook ...` line.)

Comment: Sorry! I did test with `=Hyperlink("c:\temp"). Change your formula to `=HYPERLINK("/path/to/file/")` to test or try the update above.

Comment: Unfortunately this still opens a new window, except for when the folder happens to already be selected in the window.  But if a different folder is selected it opens a new window.   Interestingly, that window is positioned exactly at the same position on the screen like the previous window.  ...